# How to sum a series of cells until cell color then continue after cell color for rest of range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, sum, series

I am trying to determine the sum of the data points between cells that have been conditionally formatted (GREEN) based on their values.

I'm not sure where to start my VBA code to sum all of the WHITE cells before a GREEN cell and place that sum in another location (ex. "A66") then sum the WHITE cells between the first GREEN cell and the second GREEN cell and place that in "A67".

I would like the code to continue summing the white cells until it gets to a green cell and then stop, place that summed value in a cell, then start a new sum for the white cells after the green cell that just caused the code to stop until it gets to the next green cell and place that value in a cell below, repeat.

I am NOT trying to sum all of the white cells in the range as a total.
[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMbwP.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be more specific on your question and post what you've done so far to try to solve your issue. Also, unless you have a very specific reason to rely on conditional formatting and then macro, I would suggest you to include the logic for selecting the cells directly on the macro.

Comment: Welcome. If you haven't written VBA before, you should start by understanding the "building blocks" of the code that will help you perform the calculation you described. For example, you'll definitely need some kind of a loop. It could be either `Do-While`, `For i=... to ...` , `For-each` etc. Depending on which approach you'll use, you'll probably need an `If ...then...else` statement. I suggest you start by calculating a simple non conditional sum and gradually add parameters to your logic. You'll find plenty of references in here. I could post the code, but the point is for you to learn.